# Is there a way to print the reference of a table?

Tags: lua

So I have this list

```lua
numbers = { "one", "two", "three" }
```

and I'm trying to print it out as

```
The table "numbers" contains the following entries: one, two, three
```

what I can't figure out is how to convert the table name to a string to print it out the way I want it to. This is what I've tried so far:

```lua
function displayList(name)
   listName = tostring(name) -- I've also tried tostring(self)

   echo("The contents of \""..listName.."\" are: "..table.concat(name, ", "))
end
```

and this returns `The contents of "table: 0000000000eb9c30" are: one, two, three` or `The contents of "nil" are: one, two, three` if I use `tostring(self)` instead.

the goal is to be able to print any list I put in the function so I don't want to hard-code "numbers" in there. I would greatly appreciate the help as I feel like I've hit a brick wall with this.

Comment: what name is printed if you do `someOtherName = numbers`? name on the left of the `=` in lua are not part of the variable. you can do what you want with a metatable and a constructor.

Comment: using the same function I posted, it just returns the address of the numbers table.

Comment: Tables do not have names. Variables do. Multiple variables can be assigned to the same table, and a variable can refer to different tables (or other values) over its life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in your example, if you refer to the table with a name you could as well just print that name.

So just call something like `displayList("numbers", numbers)`

For global tables you could do build a lookup table like

```
local nameLUT = {}
for k,v in pairs(_G) do
  nameLUT[v] = k
end
```

So

```
numbers = {1,2,3}
print(nameLUT[numbers])
```

would print `"numbers"`

A better approach would be to give your table a name via a metamethod.

```
function nameTable(t, name)
  return setmetatable(t, {__tostring = function() return name end})
end


numbers = nameTable({"one", "two", "three"}, "numbers")

print("Table " .. tostring(numbers) .. " contains " .. table.concat(numbers, ", "))
```

Of course you can use `string.format` for more advanced formatting or have `__tostring` even print the contents for you.